# How to copy the content inner HTML tag using angular 8?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want to copy the content inner HTML tag using Angular 8 but I have no idea. Someone help me, please?
My code is below:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let item of templateList">
      <div class="box mb-5">
        <div class="box__header">
          <span>
            <div [innerHtml]="item.Title"></div>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="box__body">
          <div class="icon">
            <span><button class="btn btn-outline-primary" ngbTooltip="Copy" placement="right"><i class="fa fa-clone" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></span>
            <span><button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" ngbTooltip="Download" placement="right"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></span>
          </div>
          <div [innerHtml]="item.SampleContent"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The content of div tag "<div [innerHtml]="item.SampleContent">" was display, the image here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GItJU.png)

I don't know how to copy the content inner div tag. Someone can help me?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

TS

```
data = ["<h1>1</h1>", "<h1>2</h1>", "<h1>3</h1>", "<h1>4</h1>"];
```

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data" [innerHtml]="item"></div>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-x7qhjn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Thanks for your support, but my aim is copy the content of paragraph by button. Assume that the number 1, 2, 3, 4 in your code are the paragraph. Each number have a corresponding button  and I want to copy one number in this. So how I resolve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: if you have id attribute in html element related to templateList index you can copy the value